# Superfish menu - applying hoverClass onclick to non-sub-menu items?

Tags: superfish

Bit of a weird problem that I'm finding inexplicable - would appreciate any assistance! Unfortunately I can't provide a link to the development site in question, as I don't have permission to release the password, so I'll try to describe the issue in as much detail as possible.

Basically, I have a Superfish menu set up using the standard structure, abridged code as follows:

```
<ul class="sf-menu top-level">
    <li class="level-1"><a class="level-1" href="/menu/">Menu Title</a>
        <ul>
            <li class="level-2"><a class="level-2" href="/sub-menu/">Sub-Menu Link</a></li>
            <li class="level-2"><a class="level-2" href="/sub-menu/">Sub-Menu Link</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="level-1"><a class="level-1" href="/link/">Link Title</a></li>
    <li class="level-1"><a class="level-1" href="/link/">Link Title</a></li>
</ul>
```

Menu is all working correctly as it should. However, the sfHover class - in addition to being applied to li's with child ul elements - is also being applied to li's WITHOUT child ul on click, which is resulting in styling being applied to these items without sub-menus that I don't want. I've checked the demo version of Superfish, and this anomaly also applies, so it seems to be a 'bug' with the default code, but I can't figure out how to fix it.

http://users.tpg.com.au/j_birch/plugins/superfish/#examples

Basically, I want sfHover (i.e. the class defined in sfDefaults as hoverClass) to be applied only to the items that actually have sub-menus. This is working correctly on hover, but on click applies the class across the board, which looks really weird for a split second before the new page loads in my case, as the styling applied to sfHover is very obviously only designed for items that have some sub-menu content.

I really hope that made sense, and would be incredibly grateful for anyone who can shed some light on this or suggest a workaround, as I'm tearing my hair out!